# dropdown following moving calloutbutton

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, drop-down-menu, adobe, callout

Flex Actionscript question.

I have a calloutbutton that is moving on the screen.
When I open the dropdown (by a click) it stays at the same position on the screen (only the arrow is moving). It does not follow the calloutbutton's position

I would like this dropdown to follow the position of the calloutbutton when it has moved (as it does when one clicks on the button again when it has moved).

I have tried to dispatch a MouseEvent.CLICK. It does not work.
Tried also to open, then close again dropdown with actionscript sing closeDropDown() and openDropDown(). No change.

Thanks

Sample code (call init() from creationComplete) :

```
    creationComplete="init();">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        import mx.events.DropdownEvent;

        private function init():void {
            var minuteTimer:Timer = new Timer(1*1000);
            minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateCalloutPosition);
            // starts the timer ticking
            minuteTimer.start();                
        }

        private function updateCalloutPosition(event:Event):void {
            myButton.closeDropDown();
            myButton.x = this.width * Math.random();
            myButton.y = this.height * Math.random();
//              myButton.openDropDown();
            myButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
        }

        protected function myButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (myButton.isPopUp) {
                myButton.closeDropDown();
            }
            else {
                myButton.openDropDown();
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:CalloutButton id="myButton" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)">
</s:CalloutButton>
```

Comment: Share some code. I'm pretty sure the call out pop up is positioned based on the CallOut's buttons location.  IF the button is moving, you'll also have to move the popup using the same formula.

Comment: OK, I have added some code.
Even if you remove the click handler, it will not follow the button.

Comment: Nothing in your code tries to reposition the popup when the button moves. I'm not sure how to access the popup directly, it is not obvious from the CalloutButton API.  You may have to extend the component, or you could try opening and closing the popup [there are methods for that].

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your reply. 
The popup is part of the calloutbutton spark component. And it is supposed to be automatically positioned aside the component.
Concerning the open/close suggestion :  myButton.closeDropDown and myButton.openDropDown open and close the popup. But as you can see it has no effect.
Extending the component may be a solution but I was expecting a simpler solution.

Comment: Yes, and the calloutbutton is automatically positioned near the component.  It sounds like you're moving the component after the popup is positioned and the popup is not repositioning itself.  Is this a correct description of your problem?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like my popup to reposition itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some workaround but openDuration and closeDuration is not working for DropDownList if it can be achieved than following code may help you. Hope following code may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:ArrayCollection id="ac">
            <fx:String>AK</fx:String>
            <fx:String>AL</fx:String>
            <fx:String>AR</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";

        s|DropDownList {
            openDuration: 0;
            closeDuration: 0;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;

            import spark.components.supportClasses.DropDownListBase;
            import spark.components.supportClasses.TextBase;
            import spark.events.DropDownEvent;
            import spark.skins.spark.DropDownListSkin;
            import spark.utils.LabelUtil;

            private var storeVisible:Boolean = false;

            private function init():void {
                var minuteTimer:Timer = new Timer(1*1000);
                minuteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateCalloutPosition);
                minuteTimer.start();                
            }

            private function updateCalloutPosition(event:Event = null):void {
                myButton.x = this.width * Math.random();
                myButton.y = this.height * Math.random();
                if(myButton.isDropDownOpen)
                {
                    myButton.closeDropDown(false);
                    storeVisible = true;
                }
            }

            private function updateComp():void
            {
                if(storeVisible)
                {
                    myButton.openDropDown();
                    storeVisible = false;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList id="myButton"  selectedIndex="0" dataProvider="{ac}" updateComplete="updateComp()"/> 
</s:Application>
```